# How to take 'but nonetheless regular'?

Tags: meaning

> Non-standard varieties have their own regular syntactic patterns,
> different in many respects from the patterns of the standard variety
> but nonetheless regular.

Does it have the same meaning of

> Non-standard varieties have their own regular syntactic patterns,
> different in many respects from the **regular syntactic** patterns of the standard variety
> .

Comment: In your 1st version "but they are regular" is enough to indicate the contrast "nonetheless" not necessary.

Comment: @Sam You mean 'nonetheless' is redundant?

Comment: Yes, without it,the sentence is ok to me. The speaker can only say "but are regular"

Comment: It isn't redundant; if it was omitted, there would be no point in repeating 'regular'. The point being made is that, **even though** they are very different from the standard varieties, they are still regular.

Comment: The standard and non-standard varieties [of something]  have **their own** regular syntactic patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your version doesn't mean quite the same as the original.

*Nonetheless regular* emphasises the statement made at the beginning, that non-standard varieties have regular patterns. They are *different* from the patterns of standard varieties, but, even so, they are regular.

Answer (score 0):

> The standard and non-standard varieties [of something] have *their own* regular syntactic patterns, the non-standard variety's patterns differing in many respects from those of the standard.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you mean by *the same meaning*. Your rewrite loses something from the original, which said, “Sure the non-standard varieties’ patterns are different, ***but they’re still regular***. If these patterns’ regularity is important to the author’s discussion, then your version does not mean the same thing. Your change is just as significant as altering

> She is tall and fast

to read

> She is tall.

If that passage appears in a discussion of basketball players, the alteration is not a trivial one.